# Batch file in Windows cmd does not know when java program has terminated

Tags: java, batch-file, cmd

I am using a Windows executable to do some optimisation tasks. This executable is run from a Windows Command Prompt (cmd). It reads a batch file that tells it how to run a model interface (it will need to run it multiple times) which reads and writes text files for input/output between it and the optimisation .exe program. This model interface is written in java and has been successfully compiled. My batch file looks like this:

`java -cp .;"C:\Program Files\location_of_required_jars\*" name_of_class_file`

The java program executes and completes without issue.

My issue is that the executable I am running needs to know when java has terminated. At the moment it hangs after 1 run of the model interface java program, waiting for the `java ...` line to complete.

Can anyone provide advice on how to get java to inform cmd that it has completed?

Comment: It's hard to know what you mean. When the java.exe exits the batch moves to the next line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the batch file does not progress further after running first `java` command that means that java process has not actually finished. You would need to diagnose the problem, I would suggest to first make sure that it indeed does not finish by adding some `echo` statement after `java` invocation. Next you would need to run `jps` command, which is part of JDK. `jps` will report PIDs of running java processes and then you do `jstack <pid>` to find out what is preventing your java program from terminating. It can be that main thread did not actually complete or some non daemon threads are still running.

Comment: Thank you for this - it now seems somewhat obvious. I added an echo statement to my batch file and it is never reached. I have gone back to the .java file and fixed it with `System.exit(0);` On to the next problem now.